# JavaScript array push()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add a new item in an array, but  I always get an error that `push()` is not a function. This is my object:

```
    var userInfo =
        {
            Facebook_ID:"",
            Ime:"",
            Prezime:"",
            Email:"",
            DatumRodjenja:"",
            Hometown:"",
            ProfilePictureLink: "",
            Movies:[]
        }
```

And this is my JavaScript function:

```
FB.api('/me/movies', function (response) {
        response.data.forEach(function (entry)
        {
            userInfo.Movies.push(entry.name);
        })
        });
```

I always get this error: TypeError: userInfo.Movies.push is not a function. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: There isn't sufficient code in your question to reproduce the problem. I can't see anything there that would cause it to fail to work.

Comment: `console.log(userInfo, userInfo.Movies)` It must be something other than you think it is.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/mahazo/1/edit?js,console — Cannot reproduce.

Comment: @dan08 — If that was the case, the error would be something along the lines of "Cannot read property Movies of undefined".

Comment: I've just edited my code. Please take a look now. On console.log(entry.name) i get the name of the movies, but when I want to add that name to array in JSON, the error occures. All other components of JSON(email, ...) are loaded correctly.

Comment: Oh yea, duh, comment withdrawn.

Comment: @Mato_Vilac We didn’t ask you to log `entry.name`. Whether that is defined or not is irrelevant for now. The most important thing is to log `userInfo` and `userInfo.Movies` and see whether it logs the expected result.

Comment: @Mato_Vilac —The last edit you made to your code was from before I finished constructing my test case. The problem isn't in the code you've shared.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Mato_Vilac : can you move the " var userInfo =.... " declaration inside your callback function , just before the   "response.data.forEach(...)" ?

Comment: @Thilo can you make that as answer. There is more of us on project, and it looks like there was collision in last version. Sorry guys, ty for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My *guess* is somewhere in your code you have something like this:

```
 userInfo.Movies.push = 123;
```

You overwrote the push function.

```
var userInfo =
        {
            Facebook_ID:"",
            Ime:"",
            Prezime:"",
            Email:"",
            DatumRodjenja:"",
            Hometown:"",
            ProfilePictureLink: "",
            Movies:[]
        }

        userInfo.Movies.push = 123;   // oops!

        userInfo.Movies.push("hello");
        userInfo.Movies.push("Star Wars");

        alert(userInfo.Movies[0]);
        alert(userInfo.Movies[1]);
```

Comment: Or assigned some other value: `userInfo.Movies = {}`

Comment: I wonder why somebody downvoted this answer. Currently (with no larger code part showed by the OP), this seems to be a realistic hypothesis.

Comment: It's *far* more likely that `Movies` isn't an array.

Comment: @br3nt - Yes, that would also cause the error message.   And, Juhana, I agree it's more likely.

Answer (score -2):

```
response.data.forEach(function (entry)
        {
            userInfo.Movies.push(entry.name);
        })
```

or try this

```
userInfo.Movies = response.data.map(function (entry)
        {
           return (entry.name);
        });
```